# Maui Android - Share a SQLite database between two android apps

Tags: android, sqlite, shared

I need to share a SQLite database between two or more maui apps on Android 13. My application is getting to large and I want to break it up into separate more domain specific apps but they need to share the same database. How can I do this on Android?  Windows is easy and I do not need an iOs solution.

I read something on SAF but i do not understand whether this will work for SQLite. I also see that the sharedUserId has been deprecated and I could not find another solution.

Comment: The Only solution is ContentProvider in Android. read this link https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics